# Ignore keyboard events within the click event in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, safari, dom-events

In React, while focusing elements with a keyboard, how can I detect a keyboard event within the click event in Safari? for Chrome et al. there is a workaround (https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7407) but I can't solve this exact issue in Safari, since **clientX** and **clientY** return coordinates of the focused element

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, though it feels hacky to me:

```
if (clientX > 0 && clientY > 0) {
const { bottom, right } = target.getBoundingClientRect();
return clientX + 1 === Math.round(right) && clientY + 1 === Math.round(bottom);
}
```

Safari refers to the rightmost and bottom-most corners of the focused elements, so it'd make sense to use *getBoudningClientRect* API to compare these values. Unfortunately, an unnecessary reflow is required.

If there is any better solution to this issue, I'll be happy to receive it!